# Java set persistent environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, system-properties

I have set environment varible through

```
System.setProperty("mykey" : "itsvalue");
```

I am retrieving it as :

```
System.getProperty("mykey");
```

I get the mykey retrieved properly, but when I restart my service, mykey also get erased.
How to save the mykey so that it remains persistent even after service restart?

I don't want to save it in database or cache.

Comment: It has to be serialized then stored somewhere on your drive, what about in a file?

Answer (score 0):

If you just store key value pairs java already has api for this purpose.

You can use preferences API to store key value pairs.

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071328/the-preferences-api.html

If you have lot of entries better use Database.